# how to use getdatasource(request) method

Tags: struts

new to struts i try to get database connection using datasource. any one tell me how to use getdatasource(request) method in struts...give me some example

Thanks in Advance 
Regards
Mouli V

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples from the net

http://www.javabeat.net/articles/24-introduction-to-struts-actions-3.html

http://www.jaxmag.com/itr/online_artikel/psecom,id,616,nodeid,147.html

http://struts.apache.org/1.1/faqs/database.html

Comment: thanks for ur reply....getDataSource(servlet) method is depricated in newer version of struts. I got the answer and My program working fine....these sites are very helpful to me....